# Fetching Json Data fron an URL [Error: data.map is not a function]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I can't fetch Data from this Json Data: https://flow.simpas.ai/paysagiste/article?userid=w8&businessid=ecofence_wattel_set_1_25m&companynumber=0899607494

This is The Error:  ***data.map is not a function***

You Can Check the structure of The Json to understand the Problem (The Json Data is Valid) I Check it in [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/)

**Notice:** When I try to use Json Data From [jsonplaceholder.typicode.com](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com) It's Work Fine!

### THis is The Code:

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, ScrollView,Text, View, Modal,FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { DataTable } from 'react-native-paper';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import COLORS from '../src/conts/colors';
import Button from '../src/views/components/Button';


const List = () => {



  const [data, getData] = useState([])
  const URL = 'https://flow.simpas.ai/hortus/paysagiste/category?businessid=0899607494';

  useEffect(() => {
      fetchData()
  }, [])


  const fetchData = () => {
      fetch(URL)
          .then((res) =>
              res.json())

          .then((response) => {
              console.log(response);
              getData(response);
          })
  }



return (
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1}}>
  <ScrollView>
    <Text>  List of Companies </Text>
    <Text>  Check Our Companies Details </Text>
  <DataTable >
  <DataTable.Header >
    <DataTable.Title>Businessid</DataTable.Title>
    <DataTable.Title>Title</DataTable.Title>
    <DataTable.Title>Price</DataTable.Title>
  </DataTable.Header>
  </DataTable>
  {data.map((item, i) => (
    <DataTable.Row style={styles.tableRow} key={i}>
          <DataTable.Cell> {item.businessid} </DataTable.Cell>
          <DataTable.Cell> {item.title} </DataTable.Cell>
          <DataTable.Cell> {item.price} </DataTable.Cell>
      </DataTable.Row>

                ))}

  </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>

);
};

export default List;
```

### This is the json Data:

```
{
  "articles": [
    {
      "title": "3 Wattels Set 1",
      "cover": "https://www.mybelgo.be:8444/isiweb/download/documentDownload.jsf?document=45&key=99256f5e47a9d156b66bf6b834976bd8",
      "businessid": "ecofence_wattel_set_1_25m",
      "link": "https://flow.simpas.ai/paysagiste/article?userid=w8&businessid=ecofence_wattel_set_1_25m&companynumber=0899607494",
      "description": "Ensemble de 3 wattels pour donner une dynamique à une partie de votre jardin",
      "price": "En savoir plus",
      "liked": false
    },
    {
      "title": "Arrondis 4m",
      "cover": "https://www.mybelgo.be:8444/isiweb/download/documentDownload.jsf?document=25&key=feb67f749e357b59b31fdb462649c1e4",
      "businessid": "ecofence_wattel_rounded",
      "link": "https://flow.simpas.ai/paysagiste/article?userid=w8&businessid=ecofence_wattel_rounded&companynumber=0899607494",
      "description": "Plessage arrondis de 4m x 1,8m\nIdéal pour cacher un élément du jardin comme une citerne, ...\n\nàpd de  990 eur htva.\nDemandez un devis",
      "price": "En savoir plus",
      "liked": false
    },
    {
      "title": "Cercle 3m",
      "cover": "https://www.mybelgo.be:8444/isiweb/download/documentDownload.jsf?document=32&key=653f67b47060f689c7a0419293c7136",
      "businessid": "ecofence_wattel_circle_3m",
      "link": "https://flow.simpas.ai/paysagiste/article?userid=w8&businessid=ecofence_wattel_circle_3m&companynumber=0899607494",
      "description": "Idéal pour créer un espace intime dans le jardin.",
      "price": "En savoir plus",
      "liked": false
    },
    {
      "title": "Clôture de wattel",
      "cover": "https://www.mybelgo.be:8444/isiweb/download/documentDownload.jsf?document=56&key=f889b376baefc42e244d464eef017f0",
      "businessid": "fence_wattel-_lenghtways_3_13_fromto_FROMTO",
      "link": "https://flow.simpas.ai/paysagiste/article?userid=w8&businessid=fence_wattel-_lenghtways_3_13_fromto_FROMTO&companynumber=0899607494",
      "description": "Placez un premier point, puis un second pour dessiner un wattel de la longueur que vous souhaitez. \nEnsuite, choisssez la hauteur avec le curseur.",
      "price": "En savoir plus",
      "liked": false
    },
    {
      "title": "Wattel 3x1,3m",
      "cover": "https://www.mybelgo.be:8444/isiweb/download/documentDownload.jsf?document=33&key=d3c3b8dc7d30f186663491bb6994dfb",
      "businessid": "ecofence_wattel_lenghtways_3_13",
      "link": "https://flow.simpas.ai/paysagiste/article?userid=w8&businessid=ecofence_wattel_lenghtways_3_13&companynumber=0899607494",
      "description": "Idéal pour faire une séparation tout en gardant une visibilité",
      "price": "En savoir plus",
      "liked": false
    },
    {
      "title": "Wattel 3x1,8m",
      "cover": "https://www.mybelgo.be:8444/isiweb/download/documentDownload.jsf?document=38&key=e34d959d09d6a6961894ed5531b49",
      "businessid": "ecofence_wattel_lenghtways_3_18",
      "link": "https://flow.simpas.ai/paysagiste/article?userid=w8&businessid=ecofence_wattel_lenghtways_3_18&companynumber=0899607494",
      "description": "Cacher la vue à la hauteur légale",
      "price": "En savoir plus",
      "liked": false
    },
    {
      "title": "Wattel 4x1,8m",
      "cover": "https://www.mybelgo.be:8444/isiweb/download/documentDownload.jsf?document=44&key=4464f92e9f95cb17380a7439b482e11",
      "businessid": "fence_wattel_lenghtways_4_18",
      "link": "https://flow.simpas.ai/paysagiste/article?userid=w8&businessid=fence_wattel_lenghtways_4_18&companynumber=0899607494",
      "description": "Créer des séparations d'espace avec ce module de 4m de long",
      "price": "En savoir plus",
      "liked": false
    },
    {
      "title": "Wattel 4x3m",
      "cover": "https://www.mybelgo.be:8444/isiweb/download/documentDownload.jsf?document=41&key=8acc7ab98c49d437a4d818e94342b25a",
      "businessid": "ecofence_wattel_lenghtways_4_3",
      "link": "https://flow.simpas.ai/paysagiste/article?userid=w8&businessid=ecofence_wattel_lenghtways_4_3&companynumber=0899607494",
      "description": "Créer un mur complet",
      "price": "En savoir plus",
      "liked": false
    },
    {
      "title": "Wattel 5x1,8m",
      "cover": "https://www.mybelgo.be:8444/isiweb/download/documentDownload.jsf?document=50&key=c0b6538277395083e248322834a114f9",
      "businessid": "ecofence_wattel_lenghtways_5_18",
      "link": "https://flow.simpas.ai/paysagiste/article?userid=w8&businessid=ecofence_wattel_lenghtways_5_18&companynumber=0899607494",
      "description": "",
      "price": "En savoir plus",
      "liked": false
    }
  ],
  "title": "Plessage artisanal",
  "businessid": "0899607494",
  "cover": "https://www.mybelgo.be:8444/isiweb/download/documentDownload.jsf?document=28&key=1025e35dcbdf9da271a91f4785869b",
  "pagetype": "category",
  "author": "Ecofence",
  "subtitle": "coucou",
  "moreinfotext": "Plus ...",
  "language": "fr"
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be data.articles ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `JSON` structure is only an `array` when accessed through the `articles` property, and accordingly with your code you're doing

```
getData(response);
```

but `response` at this point is an "object" and therefore has no `.map` on its prototype.

what you can do to easily overcome this is:

```
getData(response.articles);
```

Also, another point that could be an improvement is to rename the `getData` to `setData` which is more appropriate with what is really happening.

Comment: Thanks Man I use `getData(response.articles);` instead of `getData(response);` and it's Work Ihave an Other Json Data With The Same Problem if you can check it for me too:https://flow.simpas.ai/paysagiste/article?userid=w8&businessid=ecofence_wattel_set_1_25m&companynumber=0899607494

Comment: in this other `JSON` are you trying to render the whole object or a specific part?

Comment: I Want  to render the Whole object and Add element to the DataTable using for exemple {item.businessid} like The First Json

Comment: I need Help Please

Answer (score 0):

Use optional chaining:

```
{data?.articles.map((item, i) => (
```

because you try to map before data is fetched. Or you can use conditional rendering:

```
{data && data.articles.map((item, i) => (
```

Answer (score 0):

In your useState, you assume data is an object array. but you are setting an object instead of object array.

check the response contains the articles attribute and then set it to the useState. otherwise, set it as an empty array. then the issue should be resolved.

recommend using typescript with type checking so you can avoid such issues.